# I installed Python 3.4.3 over 3.4.2 on Windows 7... and now I cannot uninstall Python

Tags: python, windows

I installed Python 3.4.3 over 3.4.2 on Windows 7 and got problems with IDLE not starting.

When I use the Windows uninstaller via the control panel I get the message:

"There is a problem with this Windows Installer package a program required for this install to complete could not be run. Contact your support personnel or package vendor."

If I try to remove Python via the msi file then I get the same message.

There is no Python34 directory on my machine.  I noticed that there is an entry in the registry HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Python\PythonCore\3.4\Modules.  I didn't want to mess with my registry, but can I safely delete this entry? Is there any more to delete?

Comment: Have you looked into [this](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-windows_programs/error-1721there-is-a-problem-with-this-windows/200328d1-3310-49f2-942a-145a09041188?auth=1) or [this](https://bugs.python.org/issue22648)?

Comment: If it were me, I'd delete the C:\Python34 folder and just install Python again as a first step.  Since you said that folder is gone, did you try just installing Python again?

Answer (score 3):

I used MicrosoftFixit.ProgramInstallUninstall and I was able to remove Python34 and then it reinstalled without any problems.

Answer (score 1):

Had a similar problem. This is what I did:

Restart computer (kill any running processes of Python)

Delete the main Python folder under C drive.

Using CCleaner (or a similar application), use the Tools -> Uninstall feature to remove Python (if it is still there after deleting the folder)

Then go to the Registry window in CCleaner and clean the registry. Python should now be completely gone from your computer.